# Can't install iceweasel on RPi3 using apt-get or aptitude - Failed to fetch

Tags: software-installation, apt, aptitude

I cant install Iceweasel on my Pi for some reason.
I have tried the following options:

```
sudo apt-get install iceweasel
```

Error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  fonts-stix otf-stix fonts-oflb-asana-math fonts-mathjax mozplugger
  libgnomeui-0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  iceweasel
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 36.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 78.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main iceweasel armhf 38.7.0esr-1~deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/i/iceweasel/iceweasel_38.7.0esr-1~deb8u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

and

```
aptitude install iceweasel
```

Error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  fonts-stix otf-stix fonts-oflb-asana-math fonts-mathjax mozplugger
  libgnomeui-0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  iceweasel
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 36.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 78.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main iceweasel armhf 38.7.0esr-1~deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/i/iceweasel/iceweasel_38.7.0esr-1~deb8u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
root@raspberrypi:~# aptitude install iceweasel
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  iceweasel 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 36.3 MB of archives. After unpacking 78.0 MB will be used.
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main iceweasel armhf 38.7.0esr-1~deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
0% [Working]perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_GB.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_GB.UTF-8").
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/i/iceweasel/iceweasel_38.7.0esr-1~deb8u1_armhf.deb: 404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
```

I have tried `sudo apt-get update & upgrade` to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this before install iceweasel

apt-get update

apt-get dist-upgrade

sync

then reboot and try to install iceweasel

Comment: `apt-get dist-upgrade` did it for me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: never mind. have fun :-)

Comment: Neither `sync` nor the reboot are necessary. `apt-get update` is the relevant command in here.

Comment: not in all cases alex. check his post you will see that he tried it without succeed.